# How to extend jQuery datepicker, i needed show only Year & Months as now showing days

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to create a date picker that looks like this:

[image]

And I decided to use jQuery.

How do I implement this, with a static year that can't be changed by the user?

Comment: sorry i can't attach images, screenshot look at here: http://mediatver.ru/1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

What you are looking for is this jquery-plugin:

http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/

---

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

You can set the date format,

and disable picking a year by

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeYear: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd.MM.'
    });
});
```

Comment: it's does not approach. Main for me - design as on image in my post. I won't need show dates, Only months and years, as on my image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this example, there is no point, I had already seen.
You can just do 2 combo box.